# My PHP code is not working?

Tags: php, html, forms, input

My basic php echo is not functioning correctly?  Its simply one line and i did not think it was wrong.  If someone could please give me some pointers that would be great.  Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<form id ="myForm" action ="register.php" method="post">
    <h3>Create Username</h3>
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <h3>Create Password</h3>
    <input type ="password" name="password" id ="passwordBoxOne">
    <h3>Confirm Password</h3>
    <input type ="password" id ="passwordBoxTwo">
    <h3>Email</h3>
    <input type ="email" name="email"><br>
    <input type ="submit" value="Register" id="submitButton">
</form>
```

register.php:

```
<?php echo $_POST["username"];?>
```

When i run this code which is on a web server then nothing appears on the screen.  I was assuming that the value in the username input would appear.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your PHP error log?

Comment: `dump out` the `$_POST`. `var_dump($_POST);` and post your output.

Comment: Try doing a var_dump($_POST);

Comment: no errors as far as i can see

Comment: When i did var_dump($_POST); i got array(0) { }

Comment: oddd - files in the same directory? you are filling in the form before submitting? how is this hosted?

Comment: Just ran your code and it worked fine...

Comment: yes all files the same, yes filling out the form entirely.  Hosted through godaddy

Comment: I must be doing something absolutely horrible then

Comment: It could be GoDaddy. Their configurations are pretty strange, although I can't think of a reason. What web browser are you using?

Comment: any recommendations?

Comment: change `register.php` to `''` and use `var_dump($_POST)` on the same page where this form is

Comment: url of the form? we can check a few things

Comment: http://toymakersdev.com/registerForm.html

Comment: Kind of a silly question here. But are you hosting on a Linux or Windows environment with GoDaddy?

Comment: bingo - post vs get see the url

Comment: use var_dump($_REQUEST);

Comment: ignore him don't ever use `$_REQUEST`

Comment: @Dagon Kinda a side note, but what is wrong with `$_REQUEST` ?

Comment: its 3 things glued together, you cant be sure of the source of a variable leaving you open to attack

Comment: Got rid of the spaces and it seems to be working.  I dont know why but it did echo the username i entered.

Comment: vote closed- typo,. suggest deletion.

Comment: I would say $_REQUEST is no less safe than $_GET or $_POST or $_COOKIE, you simply shouldn't trust data inside any of these arrays.  If you don't need to distinguish whether origin of the data is $_GET or $_POST or $_COOKIE, then I see nothing wrong with using $_REQUEST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the issue is that your hosted code is not the same as your pasted code here. Using inspect element on the link you provided, you have not set the `method` attribute of the form element. By default, this is `GET`.

Add `method="POST"` to your form element.

Comment: not quite his form is `<form id = "myForm" action = "register.php" action = "post">` 2 actions :-)

Comment: Chris, his <form> element does have a method=post parameter.

Comment: It is now. Amazing how fast they can change it...

Comment: oh editing as we watch :-)

Comment: If you submit his form now, you can see the output. You guys made me do a double take.

Answer (score 0):

In the first line of the example code you posted here you wrote `method="post"` which is right but you probably forgot to write it also in the code on your page. If you try to use the form you can see in the url that the GET method is used instead. In order to work just add to the first line of the form the attribute `method` with value `post` like that:

```
<form id="myForm" action="register.php" method="post">
```

Answer (score -1):

If

```
echo $_POST["username"];
```

does not produce any output, it means that $_POST["username"] either does not exist and your error reporting settings suppress warnings, or is an empty string. It does not mean that echo is broken.

Assuming your PHP error log does not hint at any problems, the next step is to dump $_POST, e.g. through a

```
print_r ($_POST); die;
```

on the first line of register.php. If that's empty, take it from [there](https://www.google.com/search?q=%24_POST%20empty&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gl=za#channel=fs&gl=za&q=%24_POST%20empty%20site:stackoverflow.com).